# C++ Sockets LNK2019 error?

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock

everything is defined and such but its throwing me errors
so here is my code

```
#include "stdafx.h" //don't touch this.
#include <winsock.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //declaring some locals
    string results = "";
    int startupResult, connectResult, bytesSent, i = 0;
    WSADATA wsaDATA;
    SOCKET sock;
    SOCKADDR_IN socketAddr;
    char buffer[1024];
    char *msg = "Hey there!";

    //init WSA
    startupResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaDATA);
    if (startupResult != 0)
    {
        cout << "WSA Failed!!\n";
        std::cin.get();
    }

    //setting sock params
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    socketAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("Some host here.");
    socketAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    socketAddr.sin_port = htons(3040);

    //connecting the socket
    connectResult = connect(sock, (SOCKADDR *) &socketAddr, sizeof(socketAddr));
    if (connectResult != 0)
    {
        cout << "Socket Connection failed :(\n";
        std::cin.get();
    }

    //sending the data
    bytesSent = send(sock,msg,strlen(msg),0);
    cout << "Bytes sent: " << bytesSent << endl;

    //do while for um the data received...
    do
    {
        i = recv(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
        cout << "Received Data!" << endl;
        results += buffer;
    } while (i != 0);

    cout << results;
    return 0;
}
```

It's telling me that

```
_connect 
_htons 
_inet_addr 
_recv 
_send 
_socket 
_wsastartup
```

all referenced in _main but not defined?
What could be the issue, I've been having a crack at it for an hour now with no results.

Comment: Did you link your program with the winsock library?

Comment: I'm new to C++, just started a earlier today and not sure how i understand most of this code but i included #include <winsock.h>, other then that i have no idea how to include the library?

Comment: Oh wow, just realised i forgot the .dll HAHAHA woops, i'll try it and see if i can get it working.

Comment: Add `ws2_32.lib` to the libraries in the linker settings.